# Cómo cambiar de cadena un campo de tipo TIMESTAMP WITH TIME en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo el siguiente script para consultar la siguiente fecha de ejecución de los jobs en oracle:

```
SELECT  JOB_NAME,   
        JOB_ACTION, 
        SCHEDULE_TYPE,  
        NEXT_RUN_DATE

FROM    ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```

Pero el formato del campo `NEXT_RUN_DATE` es de tipo `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE` y tengo problemas para concatenar los substring de este campo, por poner un ejemplo:

```
SELECT 'Fecha: '+SUBSTR(to_char(NEXT_RUN_DATE),1,8)
FROM   ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

`ORA-01722: número no válido`
`01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"`
`*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.`
`*Action:   Specify a valid number.`

Nota: En caso que se quiera saber el "formato con el cual se muestra este campo aquí les va la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de buscar y usar algún tipo de cast pero sin exito, cualquier sugerencia sería de mucha ayuda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error se debe a la manera en que lo estás concatenando. El símbolo `+` se utiliza como operador aritmético. Para concatenar cadenas se usa el doble pike `||`.

Intenta de esta manera.

```
SELECT 'Fecha: '||SUBSTR(to_char(NEXT_RUN_DATE),1,8)
FROM   ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```